# Why wrong with the MVM&R Holder in Area 51

Tags: bug

I go and check on the [Area 51 place holder site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1321?phase=beta) to ensure we are doing what we need to be doing in order to make it out of Beta. I think there's something wrong with it, because it is showing we have zero (zed, nil, nada, none ...) users over 200 reputation. This is obviously wrong, so something must be broken, right?

Comment: It looks fine to me - it says we have 230 users with over 200 rep. It's the 4.4 questions per day that we need to work on...

Comment: @NickC ... I realize that as well. Thanks for checking, though it's working for me today as well. As I said to Larry, it must have been a glitch in the Matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working for me

[image]

Comment: It must have been a glitch in the Matrix. Works for me today as well. Thanks :D